# Как создать цифровые часы на страничке используя javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Создаю так:

```
var WatchLabel = document.createElement("label");
WatchLabel.id = "watchlabel";
HederDiv.appendChild(WatchLabel);
WatchLabel.innerHTML = (new Date()).format("hh:MM:ss");
WatchLabel.style = "position: absolute;"
                         + "right: 20px;"
                         + "top: 10%;"
                         + "width: 200px;"
                         + "background: linear-gradient(white, black);"
                         + "-webkit-background-clip: text;"
                         + "color: transparent;"
                         + "font-weight: bolder;"
                         + "font-size: 40px;" 
                         + "text-align: center;"
                         + "display: none;"
                         ;
```

Запускаю так:

```
setTimeout ('document.getElementById("watchlabel").style.display = "inline"', 1400);
setInterval('document.getElementById("watchlabel").innerHTML = (new Date()).format("hh:MM:ss");', 1000);
```

Проблема в том, что на **windows xp, pentium4 3.4 GHz, Ram 1 GB, chrome версии 50+**
такие часы подвисают, секунды ходят через одну. 
Подскажите что можно сделать?

Comment: Ну сниппет что ли сделай.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Не надо передавать в setTimeout и setInterval строки. Передавай функции.
2. Не надо заставлять браузер парсить html-разметку, когда у тебя текст. Используй textContent вместо innerHTML.
3. Зачем там куча кода со стилями? Напиши их сразу руками.
4. Перепиши форматирование даты.
5. Откажись от градиетного текста или используй svg.